# Gracefully Crashing System

Tags: 22.04, crash

I am completely at a loss for what to search for next. I recently switched from Windows 11 to Ubuntu. The reason why I switched is because I was having an issue on Windows 11 that made my system gracefully crash to the lock screen after "Stuttering" a bit. I couldn't find a solution despite reaching out to a few communities and decided I was going to reinstall a the OS. I figured that would be a good time to just install Ubuntu and make the switch. Now that I'm on Ubuntu it's been great and I don't think I'll go back to Windows. The problem is still persisting though into Ubuntu. I am not sure if it's a driver issue or if its the hardware itself that's failing me.

How can I determine the source of this issue from the Ubuntu OS? I've attached logs from "Important" shortly after the most recent crash. I'm sorry this question may come across as lacking focus and I'm hoping with direction I can narrow in my question. Thanks everyone for your help!

```
01:06:19 bluetoothd: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
01:01:21 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
01:01:20 gdm3: GLib: Source ID 95 was not found when attempting to remove it
01:00:52 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
00:59:03 bluetoothd: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
00:59:03 bluetoothd: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
00:59:03 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
00:59:03 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
Sep 10 23:50:02 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
Sep 10 23:50:02 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Sep 10 23:49:59 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Sep 10 23:49:54 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Sep 10 23:49:27 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
Sep 10 23:49:20 bluetoothd: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
Sep 10 23:49:20 kernel: 
Sep 10 23:49:19 kernel: ucsi_ccg 4-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
Sep 10 23:49:19 kernel: nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
Sep 10 23:49:19 kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
```

Updates:

-@Artur Meinild mentioned an interesting log line: 00:59:03 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02. Quick google search yielded other linux users on Lenovo laptops (of various models)  Some had success restarting the bluetooth driver, I have not had that success as some also have mentioned. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=276815

- Its been full force today and I've isolated the set of logs that occur each time the error happens. See below

  `20:43:07 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:43:07 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:43:07 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:43:07 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:43:07 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:43:03 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:43:03 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:43:03 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:43:03 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:42:58 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:42:58 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:42:58 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:42:58 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

  20:42:55 bluetoothd: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters

  20:42:55 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02

  20:42:54 gdm3: GLib: Source ID 85 was not found when attempting to remove it`

Comment: Since the issue persists between OSes, it seems like a hardware malfunction. Also, this log line seems "interesting": `01:01:21 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02`

Comment: @ArturMeinild I just did a quick google search and I found someone mentioning the same line and they also have a Lenovo brand laptop (Not the Same model) experiencing this issue. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=276815

Comment: I also see same errors in my logs when run dmesg and facing strange issue as well that my Ubuntu starts with some delay till Login screen, but when I enter my credentials, gnome sessions sometime crashes and hang my system with freezed screen. Facing it in 3 out of 5 login attempts. :( . Still checking for the actual problem and solution. 
I have ASUS ROG Strix GA35 desktop with nvidia 2080ti and AMD Ryzen-9 processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scrolled through my "All" logs section and searched around the event times and found that the first logged item each time was actually "Lid closed". I thought this was interesting and investigated how the lid sensor worked on my specific laptop which. My laptop the sensor is located to the sides of the laptop and are operated via magnets. I noticed my specific mouse, the Razer Naga Pro has interchangeable side plates that are held on by magnets. I was able to reproduce the issue by pressing where the magnet is on the mouse side plate to the sensor location on the laptop.

Very unique to my situation and plenty of red herrings everywhere. I've lessened the blow by using `sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and editing all the switches for lid sensors responses to `ignore` along with removing the comment out's #. This made it so when the lid sensor is activated it ignores it. This just means when I hibernate my laptop, it has to be done manually now. But its better than the alternative so I can keep using my expensive mouse.